# Convtranspose2D in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I have to use `ConvTranspose2d` for an input noise of (16,100) of my GAN  generator in tensorflow, without a dense layer. Any suggestions ?

I saw it is possible in pytorch but not in tensorflow.

For background information :
[convert a pytorch generator to tensorflow](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/convert-a-pytorch-generator-to-tensorflow/89952)

Answer (score 0):

> Lets assume , your data is x and it has a shape (16,100) , and your
> batch size is 'b'. So to feed your input of size (16,100) , you have
> to reshape your input as convtranspose2d requires 4 dimensional input
> (batch_size , height , width , channel). so you will reshape as
> follows:

`x = x.reshape((16,100,1))`

> where last axis is the channel axis.
>
> Now when you feed the input in convtranspose2d is will have argument
> of input_shape parameter as (16,100,1) and automatically add batch
> size axis to the input which will make it 4 dimensional , now the
> shape is (b,16,100,1).